Would this modified Tesla Valve improve performance?
I'm wondering if adding more loops, perhaps even in increasingly smaller loops (like a fractal) could improve a tesla valve's performance, or would the difference be negligible? This is what I was thinking:


I'd have to think about the general case for a bit, but that particular configuration would break the valve.  It depends on the flow from one side to counteract the other.  If your fractal element slows one side down, it's going to fail to counteract the other side that wasn't slowed.

Oh ok, thank you.
